# Changes in lua language cause error in ai script

Tags: automation, lua

When I run script in game, I got an error  message like this:

.\AI\haick.lua:104: bad argument #1 to 'find' (string expected, got nill)

```
local haick = {}

    haick.type          = type
    haick.tostring      = tostring
    haick.require       = require
    haick.error         = error
    haick.getmetatable  = getmetatable
    haick.setmetatable  = setmetatable
    haick.ipairs        = ipairs
    haick.rawset        = rawset
    haick.pcall         = pcall
    haick.len           = string.len
    haick.sub           = string.sub
    haick.find          = string.find
    haick.seed          = math.randomseed
    haick.max           = math.max
    haick.abs           = math.abs
    haick.open          = io.open
    haick.rename        = os.rename
    haick.remove        = os.remove
    haick.date          = os.date
    haick.exit          = os.exit
    haick.time          = GetTick
    haick.actors        = GetActors
    haick.var           = GetV

    -->  General > Seeding Random:

    haick.seed(haick.time())

    -->  General > Finding Script Location:

    local scriptLocation = haick.sub(_REQUIREDNAME, 1, haick.find(_REQUIREDNAME,'/[^\/:*?"<>|]+$'))
```

Last line (104 in file) causes error and I don`t know how to fix it.
There are links to .lua files below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F90v-h4VjDb0rZUCUETY9684PPGw7IVG/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fi_wmM3rg7Ov33yM1uo7F_7b-bMPI-Ye/view?usp=sharing

Help, pls!

Comment: You should giva a link to what is above your fragment, so that we can find, where `_REQUIREDNAME` is supposed to be set.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a function in Lua, you are expected to pass valid arguments for the function.

To use a variable, you must first define it, _REQUIREDNAME in this case is not available, haick.lua file is incomplete. The fault is of the author of the file.

Lua has a very useful reference you can use if you need help, see [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4)